# Microsoft office 2013 text cursor animation for windows system

Tags: windows, microsoft-office-2013

I'm curious, is it possible to use Microsoft office 2013 text cursor animation for windows system. 
By this i mean the smooth animation it has..?

(Noob alert)
EDIT (Tip: from comment):
OS: Windows 8.1
+


What i mean is exactly what techie007 says:

> If you use Office 2013 with GPU acceleration turned on the input cursor doesn't just blink, it fades in and out, and line scrolls are pixel-by-pixel animations and such. To make things appear smoother.

Just want to know if this is possible

Comment: Do you mean you want to show it like this: 'I' ? I mean as the pointer change when you select a text?

Comment: @mok If you use Office 2013 with GPU acceleration turned on the input cursor doesn't just blink, it fades in and out, and line scrolls are pixel-by-pixel animations and such.  To make things appear smoother.

Comment: @Egghead Please edit your questions and specify which Windows OS version(s) you are interested in.  While this is an Office 2013-specific thing, there maybe something similar for Windows 8(.1) due to the new GPU rendering used for the desktop, but I doubt you'll find anything for Windows 7 and earlier.  If you did it'd probably be a completely different/3rd party solution.

Comment: Short answer: No, it's not possible